# Displaying two divs inline. Why does display:inline have to be in the nested div?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Here is my css:

```
#help-someone {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0.7em;
}

#complete-loan {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is my code in my application.html.erb

```
<% if pending_loans.present? %>
      <div id="help-someone" class="alert alert-success">Help someone today and <div id="complete-loan"> <%= link_to "complete your loan", pending_loan_path %>.</div></div>
<% end %>
```

So this works. It is rendering inline like I want. But I initially thought that the display:inline-block should be in the help-someone id and not the nested id. Why is this?

Also is margin auto the best way to center my entire div box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. display inline block needs to go in the complete-loan element, otherwise it would display as a block level element. You could also apply this to the #help_someone id, but it is not necessary.

Inline block allows containers to display inline, but be formatted using block level properties.

2. margin auto is the best way to center your entire div box.